# Unable to use asksaveas function

Tags: python, tkinter, youtube

I am making a GUI application where user can download any video from youtube, below is the code I am using:

```
from pytube import YouTube
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.filedialog import *
from threading import *

root=Tk()

root.iconbitmap('yticon.ico')
root.title('Youtube Video Downloader')
root.resizable(0,0)

file_size=0
url=''

def downThread():
    p1=Thread(target=downloader)
    p1.start()
def progress(chunk,file_handle,remaining):
    global download_status
    file_download=file_size-remaining
    per=(file_download/file_size)*100
    download_status.config(text='{:00.0f}% downloaded'.format(per))

def downloader():
    global file_size, download_status, url
    download_btn.config(state=DISABLED)
    download_status.place(x=200, y=250)
    #try:
    link=url.get()
    path=asksaveasfilename(title='Save File', defaultextension='.mp4', filetype=(('*.mp4', 'MP4 Files')))
    yt=YouTube(link, on_progress_callback=progress)
    video=yt.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4').first()
    file_size=video.filesize
    #assert isinstance(video, bytes)
    video.download(path)
    download_status.config(text='Download Finished...')
    res=messagebox.askyesno('Youtube Downloader','Do You want to download another video?')
    if res==1:
        url.delete(0,END)
        download_btn.config(state=NORMAL)
        download_status.config(text=' ')
    else:
        root.destroy()
    #except Exception as e:
     #   download_status.config(text='Failed!!There was an error')

imgfile=PhotoImage(file='yticon1.png')
back_img=Label(root, image=imgfile)
back_img.place(x=0,y=0,relwidth=1,relheight=1)
entr_url=Label(root, text='Enter Url', font='Algerian 15 bold')
entr_url.place(x=20,y=40)
url=Entry(root, width=30, bd=2, relief=SUNKEN, font=('Calibiri(Body)', 12))
url.place(x=140, y=40)
btnimg=PhotoImage(file='yt.png')
download_btn=Button(root, width=99, height=50, relief=RIDGE, activebackground='red', image=btnimg, command=downThread, bd=7)
download_btn.place(x=220, y=170)
download_status=Label(root, text='Please Wait...', font=('Arial',15))
root.geometry('700x400+150+150')
root.mainloop()
```

But when I run this code then it gives this error, how do I solve it?

```
_tkinter.TclError: bad file type ".mp4", should be "typeName {extension ?extensions ...?} ?{macType ?macTypes ...?}?"
```

Comment: `path=asksaveasfilename(title='Save File', defaultextension='.mp4',filetype=[('*.mp4','mp4 File')])`
you have to do this

Comment: `filetype=(('*.mp4', 'MP4 Files'))` should be `filetype=(('MP4 Files', '*.mp4'),)` or `filetype=[('MP4 Files', '*.mp4')]`.

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks it works but when I download the video with the name specified in asksaveasfilename dialog then it will create a directory with that name and name of video file remains unchanged

Comment: The first argument of `download()` function is the output folder and the second argument is the filename.  So you should call it like: `folder, filename = os.path.split(path)` followed by `video.download(output_path=folder, filename=filename)`.

Answer (score 0):

link=url.get()

`path=asksaveasfilename(title='Save File', defaultextension='.mp4',filetype=(('*.mp4', 'MP4 Files')))`

yt=YouTube(link, on_progress_callback=progress)
[('*.mp4','mp4 File')])`
you have to do this because the filetype will be in list form.

Comment: `('*.mp4', 'MP4 File')` should be `('MP4 File', '*.mp4')`.

Comment: Probably not this worked in my side and i always do like this.

Comment: According to [document](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/dialog.html), *filetypes - a sequence of (label, pattern) tuples*.

Comment: but how does mine code works? I use (pattern,label) to do this and it works as well

Comment: The dialog  will show up, but files for the pattern will not be shown.